# How to remove Upload picture lable from registration page?

Tags: users, media

how to remove Upload picture lable from avatar image field.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this should work. Use form id alter hook to remove the label from image field.

```
function yourmodule_form_user_register_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

 // Search for the field you want to alter 

 // unset the label using $form['search_image_field_name'] or remove the label using empty string for that form field.
}
```